# "locateOnScreen()" is really slow

Tags: python, computer-vision, pyautogui

I have been using the following code from the pyautogui module:

```
locateOnScreen()
```

to locate image files. If you haven't seen the locateOnScreen() function before, this is how you use it:

```
location = pyautogui.locateOnScreen("Image", confidence = 0.3) # confidence is optional
```

The problem with using that is that it takes time to find the images. I was wondering if there is a way to make it work faster so the program can find more objects. There might not be a way, I was just wondering. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to switch to openCV! Sorry for any issues with my dumb question!

Comment: How do you switch to openCV?

Comment: Fractale I used template matching from openCV. You can find tutorials on YouTube about it of you are interested!

Comment: Can I use template matching with my screen?

Comment: Mehran Jalili yes you can feed the template matching script with your live screen.

Comment: This youtube series might help:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ks4MPfMq8aQ